# In JavaScript doing a simple shipping and handling calculation

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with a simple JavaScript calculation. My document is supposed to add $1.50 to an order if it is $25 or less, or add 10% of the order if it is more then $25. The exact problem is:

Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling charge for purchases. Create a Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box and includes a JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script that adds a minimum shipping and handling charge of $1.50 for any purchase that is less than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling charge. The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the formula for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which results in a shipping and handling charge of $5.00. After you determine the total cost of the order (purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box.

This is my code:

```
    var price = window.prompt("What is the purchase price?", 0);
var shipping = calculateShipping(price);
var total = price + shipping;
function calculateShipping(price){
if (price <= 25){
 return 1.5;
}
else{
 return price * 10 / 100
}
}
window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");
```

When testing I enter a number in the prompt box, and instead of calculating as if I entered a number it calculates as if I entered a string. i.e. i enter 19 and it gives me 191.5 or I enter 26 and it gives me 262.6

Comment: Use `parseInt` to convert the prompted input to a number. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: `parseInt()` for money values? Naaah.

Comment: @Dutchie - Technically its better to handle money values as an int, anyway. I.e. store it as cents (or pence - I'm english) and then do the division when you want to display.

Comment: Still @dutchie fair enough, I wasn't paying attention. `parseFloat` is probably the more fitting

Comment: @James - no one is storing anything in the above example. The user is inputing the money value into a text box. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dutchie - No you are not mising anything. It was a bonus thought for if you are storing a money related field. Worth clarifying though, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `parseFloat` will help you:

```
var price = parseFloat(window.prompt("What is the purchase price?", 0))
var shipping = parseFloat(calculateShipping(price));
var total = price +shipping;
function calculateShipping(price){
if (price <= 25){
 return 1.5;
}
else{
 return price * 10 / 100
}
}
window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");
```

See it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/e8U6W/

Also, a little-known put more performant way of doing this would be simply to `-0`:

```
var price =window.prompt("What is the purchase price?", 0) - 0;
```

(See: [Is Subtracting Zero some sort of JavaScript performance trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665984/is-minus-zero-some-sort-of-javascript-performance-trick))

Be sure to comment this, though as its not as obvious to those reading your code as `parseFloat`

Comment: Thanks all of you! I knew about parseFloat() and parseReal(), but was not sure how to use them....My code works now!!

Comment: No worries. Do you want to accept that then (click the tick)?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily convert a string to a  number

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm

basically JS provides parseInt and parseFloat methods...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to cast your text results into float values using `parseFloat()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to the s/o question *"Javascript adding two numbers incorrectly"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638074/javascript-adding-two-numbers-incorrectly/4600744#answer-4600744).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of redundant multiplication, but your problem is that the numbers that are being inputted are treated as strings, not numbers. You have to convert them to floating point numbers:

```
var price = parseFloat(window.prompt("What is the purchase price?", 0));
var shipping = calculateShipping(price);
var total = price + shipping;

function calculateShipping(price)
{
  if (price <= 25)
  {
   return 1.5;
  } else {
    return price / 10
  }
}

window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = parseFloat(window.prompt("What is the purchase price?", 0)); 
var shipping = calculateShipping(price); 
var total = price + shipping; 
function calculateShipping(price){ 
  var num = new Number(price);
  if (num <= 25){  
    return 1.5; 
  } else{  
    return num * 10 / 100 
  } 
} 
window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: I am curious as to why you would add this line: var num = new Number(price);

Comment: The primary reason is for argument validation (not to assume that a float would be passed).  A alternative reason is to ensure that a numeric variable is used for the calucaltion of the shipping price.