# Can't get operator to work

Tags: javascript

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FF1OPHNA043Z

I am playing around on w3school.com and while I can get operators such as (*),(/) to work, I can't get the addition or subtraction operators to work.

For example, in the link:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
var y = x * 2
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
```

will result in whatever x is times 2.
But when I try to use

```
+ or -
```

The result will be whatever x is plus 2.  Or like below if x is 2.

```
22
```

Is x being treated as an Object?

Comment: `x` is a string. `x + 2` performs string concatenation. `x - 2` should work fine though.

Comment: x is being treated like a string.

Comment: try making that var x=parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value ) -- What's happening is it's concatenating a string with plus.

Comment: I'm guessing that what you say about it not working with `-` is not correct. The `+` operator, when the left side is a string, concatenates.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Doesn't matter which side. If one operand is a string, concatenation is performed.

Comment: Well, then, my statement still holds true :P.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force JS to do math instead of putting two strings together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `x` is a String and thus the `+` operator adds the String `2` to your `x` String.  Try parsing it into an integer to perform mathematical operations safely.

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value, 10);
var y = x + 2
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to say string. Don't know why I put Objects, lol

Answer (score 1):

Nope, `x` is a *string*.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var value = input.value;
console.log(value, typeof value);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2" />
```

Since `+` is also used for string concatenation, the designer of JS decided that in this case, it would treat any actual numbers like strings and concatenate them.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var value = input.value + 2; // Basically turns in to "2" + "2"
console.log(value, typeof value);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2" />
```

This, however, doesn't apply to `-`:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var value = input.value - 2; // Equivalent to 2 - 2 === 0
console.log(value, typeof value);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2" />
```

So what you need to do is convert the string to a number. My personal favorite is using the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var value = Number(input.value) + 2;
console.log(value, typeof value);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2" />
```

You also could use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), which is functionally equivalent to `Number`, or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you want a non-floating point value and/or want to specify the base.

Comment: Let's not forget `var value = +input.value + 2;` :)