# Addition in React JSX - A + B

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addition, jsx

In my `JSX`, I'm mapping through `API` data and then display the values, from the object array.

Except in my `JSX`, I want to add two prices together, from my data.  Something like this.

```
<div className="right">
  <p>
    from <span>£{(phone.priceInfo.hardwarePrice.oneOffPrice.gross + phone.priceInfo.hardwarePrice.oneOffPrice.gross)}</span> upfront cost
  </p>
</div>
```

However, let's say `phone.priceInfo.hardwarePrice.oneOffPrice.gross === 10`, then in my `DOM`, the following returns `£10+£10`, rather than `£20`.

How do I do an addition sum, in my `JSX`?

Comment: Answered - duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together

Comment: remember that input received from HTML elements is _always_ string data. If you need numbers, use `parseFloat` before you do things that assume numbers (rather than `parseInt`).