# Adding two variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addition

I want to take a number input (id="number") and save it as "x". Then make another variable, "y", that is 5% of "x". And then I want to add them together and save the result in a variable called "result".
Let's say that x = 100. Then y = 5. If I would just alert "y" it would alert the number 5 which is correct but the problem is that when I try to alert "result" (x+y) it alerts 1005 (it doesn't add the numbers just write them next to each other).

```
let x = document.getElementById("number");
let y = x*0.05;
var result = x+y;
alert(result);
```

Comment: document.getElementById("number"); will give you an element, you need to get its value using `.value` if its and input or user `.textContent` if it has text within it - also you need to cast the string to an int once you have retrieved the input

Comment: That sounds like it's doing a string concatenation, not an addition. I'll search how to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Fist get `value` and so convert it to `number`:

**Change :**

```
var x = document.getElementById("number")
```

**to :**

```
var x = parseInt( document.getElementById("number").value )
```

> Note : You must convert the input to a number even if `type` property be equal with `number`.

```js
function fun() {
  var x = document.getElementById('number').value;
  console.log( typeof x)
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
  console.log( typeof y)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number">
<button onclick="fun()">Go..</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you need a **value** for doing some calculation. so,

   var x = document.getElementById("number").value;
2. "+" operator will concatenate if string value exist. var x is string value but automatic type casting will occur when var y=x*0.05. so you must cleary declaire "x is number" via **parseInt()**.

   var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);

Now "+" operator will work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is `x+y` is performing [string concatenation](http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html), not integer addition--which is what you want.

```
// String concatenation
console.log("100" + "5"); // outputs "1005"

// Integer Addition
console.log(100 + 5); // outputs "105"
```

That's the problem, but what's the solution?

The solution is to [force integer addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together) with something like `parseInt()` (as [Ehsan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54918165/10957435))

```
var x = parseInt( document.getElementById("number").value );
```

> Worth noting is the fact that Ehsan uses document.getElementById("number").**value**, instead of document.getElementById("number")

This forces x to be an int, which will allow `x+y` to perform integer addition.

P.S. I should also note part of the reason for your problem is related to the fact that `document.getElementById("number").value` is a string, forcing a [type conversion](https://javascript.info/type-conversions) to take place

> Addition ‘+’ concatenates strings
>   Almost all mathematical operations convert values to numbers. A notable exception is addition +. If one of the added values is a string, the other one is also converted to a string.
>
> Then, it concatenates (joins) them:
>
> ```
> alert( 1 + '2' ); // '12' (string to the right)
> alert( '1' + 2 ); // '12' (string to the left)
> ```
>
> This only happens when at least one of the arguments is a string. Otherwise, values are converted to numbers.

Meaning that one of the operands (again, document.getElementById("number").value is a string) in an addition operation being a string forces both to become strings and get concatenated.