# Google Apps Script concatenating numbers rather than adding

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, sum

I wrote the code below to grab a portion of a column of numbers and add them up. However, the function is concatenating numbers rather than adding.

I'm getting this result:

```
0AMOUNT120123126129132135138141144147
```

But if I run it from Dec on the sum should be:
432

My code in Google Scripts:

```js
//add sum and input it into the total column
function sum(startMonth, startColumn, lastRow){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  startColumn = startColumn +1;
  var sum = 0;
  var currAmount = 0;
  var k = 0;
  for(k = startMonth; k <= lastRow; k++){
   currAmount = sheet.getRange(k, startColumn).getValue();
   sum += currAmount;   //currAmount + sum;
   Logger.log(sum);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(k, startColumn).setValue(sum);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(k, startColumn).setBackground("Yellow");
  return sum;
}
```

And a snapshot of my sheet:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is the hint: That's not a number being added. That's strings being concatenated.

```
   currAmount = sheet.getRange(k, startColumn).getValue();
   sum += currAmount;   //currAmount + sum;
```

Specifically, this is the main problem. Regardless of whether the number returned by `getValue()` is a number or not, you add it to `sum`.

A few ways to fix this would be to adjust the value of `k`, to check the `typeof` the value, or coerce the value into a number, depending on exactly what you're trying to do. This is essentially a javascript problem, with the canonical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together)

Also, generally you should [batch operations where possible](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices); e.g., instead of running `getRange().getValue()` every go through a for-loop, you are much better using (as an example, may need tweaking)

```
var amounts = sheet.getRange(startMonth, startColumn, (lastRow - startMonth), 1);
for(var k = startMonth; k <= lastRow; k++){
 sum += amounts[k][0]
 Logger.log(sum);
}
```