# Swing java JComboBox disappears whenever I write in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have a main `JFrame` pane using Swing in Java with a `JComboBox` embedded in it with a number of selections.

Everything initiates well on opening but when I write inside the `JTextField`, the words in the JComboBox disappear.

I'm initiating my `JComboBox` in in the following way:

```
private static String[] options = new String[] {"Search your own pasted text" ,  "Search your own file", 
        "Search website", "Search Lyric Database", "Search Books Database"};
private static JComboBox<String> bookList = new JComboBox<>(options);
```

Then I initiate the JTextField in this way

```
private static JTextField textFieldTheme = new JTextField(50); 
private static String theme = textFieldTheme.getText();
```

Have no idea why they interfere with each other....everything works fine still.  In fact, I can stick click the the `JComboBox` menu, its just that it resizes and the words disappear from it

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: All the static variables are in indicator of poor class design. I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for a better design. Download the working example and replace the text area with your combo box. That is start with a working example ant make a simple change. Then if it stops working you know what you changed and you can ask a specific question.

Comment: You don't seem to have accepted any answers. Doing so helps all (including you, when it encourages people not to begin ignoring you).

Comment: @AndrewThompson hi Andrew thanks for the feedback... For some reason the answers are only showing up as comments. Can you advise on how to accept them as answers

Comment: See the comment I made on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387012/418556) before commenting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the JTextField was interfering with the JTextArea and somehow that was making it so the JComboBox menu text disappeared if I wrote something into the JTextField.

I wound up turning the JTextField into a custom JTextArea -- while it wasn't ideal, it did allow the JComboBox to work without the text disappearing.

I used this code to turn the JTextArea into a JTextField:

```
JTextArea textFieldTheme = new JTextArea(textAreaText, 1, 50);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textFieldTheme.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.OUT_BOTTOM);
```

ADAPTED FROM THIS HELPFUL POST:
[Java / Swing : JTextArea in a JScrollPane, how to prevent auto-scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972337/java-swing-jtextarea-in-a-jscrollpane-how-to-prevent-auto-scroll/3973103#3973103)

Answer (score 0):

Per above code you wrote, all looks fine.
Maybe better to add also your main frame code to see how you adding the components.

Anyway you can follow instructions [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)