# The Adding function doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

when i'm using the function to add two numbers together it appears next to each other like (2+2=22)
although it works well with other mathematical operators (* and /)

```
    <html>
  <head>
    
        <title>Adding</title>
    
    
  </head>

  <body>
      
      <input type="number" id="one">
      <input type="number" id="two">
      <button id="press">seed</button>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function adding (a, b){
                return (a + b);
                }
        document.getElementById("press").onclick = function(){
            var first = document.getElementById("one").value;
            var second = document.getElementById("two").value;
                
            alert(adding(first, second));
        }
        
    </script>
    
  </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force JS to do math instead of putting two strings together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the string "2" plus "2" hence they are just appended. You will need to typecast into a number first.

```
console.log(parseInt("2")+Number("2"))
```

Comment: You can use Number() constructor for both of them or parseInt for both of them why different ?

Comment: i want the numbers to be recognized when type them in the website

Comment: Simply to showcase various ways to turn a string into a number.

Comment: `var second = Number(document.getElementById("two").value);` 

should do the trick =)

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute returns a string, for which the `+` operator is defined to concatenate. You can use the unary plus operator to simply convert them to a numbers.

```js
function adding(a, b) {
  return (a + b);
}
document.getElementById("press").onclick = function() {
  var first = +document.getElementById("one").value;
  var second = +document.getElementById("two").value;

  alert(adding(first, second));
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="one">
<input type="number" id="two">
<button id="press">seed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only write parseint where you return.

```js
 function adding (a, b){
    return (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
}
document.getElementById("press").onclick = function(){
    var first = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var second = document.getElementById("two").value;

    alert(adding(first, second));
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="one">
<input type="number" id="two">
<button id="press">seed</button>
```